# Can I specify certain files for Dropbox to ignore?

Tags: linux, dropbox

I'd like to sync configuration folders for specific applications on my Linux machines, namely configuration for [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey) (a text-expansion and keyboard-macro automation suite), which lives at `~/.config/autokey/`.

Though I know that it's relatively simple to just symlink `~/Dropbox/Apps/AutoKey` to `~/.config/autokey/`, I'd specifically like to ignore certain files in the folder if possible. There are notably a log file and a PID file that I'd prefer to ignore.

Is there a way to specify configuration  for Dropbox which will make it ignore these files, or even better, glob patterns? (e.g. `Apps/AutoKey/*.log`, `Apps/AutoKey/*.pid`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude folders with the help of the dropbox-cli (dropbox.py) exclude command found [here](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli#EXCLUDE), but I don't think you can exclude single files.
I'd recommend the 'symlink individual files from that folder' approach.

Comment: They really need to enable this feature. Something similar to a `.gitignore` file or configuration passed in each directory's `.dropbox` file would go a long way.